# My Link in react won't work when clicked on

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

When i click on the links, they wont work. But when I change the position in `ul.pullRight li:before` to `relative`, the styling disappears and the link works. There's a hover effect in the links.[image]

> **This is my NavBar component**

```
 import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


const Navbar = ({ icon, title }) => {

    return (
        <nav className='navbar bg-primary'>
            <h1 style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '35px', color: 'whitesmoke'}}><i className={icon}></i>{title}</h1>
            <ul className='container pullRight'>
                {/* LINK to is used in place of <a> tag */}
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/logout">LogOut</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

> This is the css file

```
/* Pull right  */
ul.container li
{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 15px Raleway;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.pullRight li:before
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    content: '';
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

ul.pullRight li:hover:before
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i'm assuming that you don't want to `li:before` to be clicked so you can add this to the css, `pointer-events: none` and it won't cover the initial element anymore.

i did not test this, but please do test and tell if it worked.

Comment: no problem, please confirm the answer so people know it has been solved.